# How to use kplot (Cairo plotting library) without installing it

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

[kplot](https://kristaps.bsd.lv/kplot/) is a UNIX programming library for plotting graphs on a Cairo surface. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/kristapsdz/kplot).
After downloading the source code I extraced it to the directory **kplot-master** and **cd** into it. Simple **ls** now shows

```
array.c      
border.c       
bucket.c       
buffer.c 

....

example0.c  
example1.c

....
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Cairo is installed in my system and I tested it by successfully compiling C codes available in [zetcode dot com slash gfx slash cairo slash cairobackends slash] (Sorry as I am not allowed to link more than two).

I am new to GTK and Cairo plotting library and would like help in the following directions:

1. I do not want to install kplot in my system.
2. I just want to learn how kplot uses Cairo.

When I use the following command:

```
gcc example0.c -o example `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

it produces the following error message:

```
example0.c:17:20: fatal error: compat.h: No such file or directory
#include "compat.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

It will be very helpful if somebody shows me how to test those kplot examples without installing it.

Comment: well, your compiler needs to know where you've put theses .h files its looking for. Copying them to a default location is what you'd call installation. Without that, you need to read `man gcc` and figure out which options (mainly `-I` and `-L` you need. But: you will still need to compile kplot if you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, you will need to install that to your system to use it. Look inside the Makefile to see if you can install it to a custom prefix so you can put it in a nonstandard location, say `/opt/otherlibs` or so.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to install.

First you will need to compile the  kplot library. For that, `cd` to the kplot directory and run a `make` command. This will generate the file `compat.h`. After that you will be able to compile example by example with `make example(n)` command, or with `` gcc example(n).c -o example(n) `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` libkplot.a -lbsd -lm `` command.

If you have GTK+-3.0 and Cairo dev libraries installed, everything should go well.